# SSS_INVALID_SRCH_FILTER in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I am getting the below error in production system for a scheduled script , whereas the code works perfectly fine in Sandbox Environment.

PS: I don't have reputation to upvote kindly excuse.

Comment: can you add code snippet of saved search related code from scheduled script?

Comment: Execution Time: 0.39s
Script Usage: 10
Script: NS|SC|Email Bill Payment Approvers
Type: Scheduled
Function: scheduled_emailBillPaymentApprovers
Error: SSS_INVALID_SRCH_FILTER
An nlobjSearchFilter contains invalid search criteria: custbody_emailed_to_approvers.
Stack Trace: nlapiCreateSearch(PhilzCoffee_SC_EmailBillPaymentApprovers.js$226927:543)
<anonymous>(PhilzCoffee_SC_EmailBillPaymentApprovers.js$226927:262)
scheduled_emailBillPaymentApprovers(PhilzCoffee_SC_EmailBillPaymentApprovers.js$226927:108)
<anonymous>(PhilzCoffee_SC_EmailBillPaymentApprovers.js$226927:413)

Comment: The code snippet is `var arrBillPaymentFilters = [];
  arrBillPaymentFilters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('custbody_emailed_to_approvers', null, 'is', 'F'));
  arrBillPaymentFilters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('tobeprinted', null, 'is', 'F'));
  arrBillPaymentFilters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('custbody_to_be_printed', null, 'is', 'T'));
  arrBillPaymentFilters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T'));`

Comment: `// Flag Vendor Payment as emailed to approvers
     nlapiSubmitField('vendorpayment', intBillPaymId, 'custbody_emailed_to_approvers', 'T');
     nlapiLogExecution('AUDIT', stLogTitle, 'SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED VENDOR PAYMENT ' + intBillPaymId);`

Comment: does the custom field "custbody_emailed_to_approvers" exists in production systems? (check transaction body fields) If yes, then what is the data type in production?

Answer (score 3):

there could be two possibilities for the error in production

1) Transaction body field `custbody_emailed_to_approvers` exists in Sandbox but not in production

2) The data type of field `custbody_emailed_to_approvers`  in Production is not Checkbox

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the issue , in production it was not checkbox, probably it scrolled to something else when i saved. Thanks a lot once again.